# Java: Code not running after for loop?

Tags: java, dom

```
  public static String getElementXpath(DOMElement elt){
        String path = ""; 

        for (; elt != null; elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode()){

            System.out.println("THIS ONE " + path);
        }
        System.out.println("NEXT ONE " + path);
        return path;                            
    }
```

NEXT ONE doesn't even print. I've tried adding anything after the for loop but they don't seem to be running. Shouldn't there be exception that is raised that I can catch? My main method which executes the function getElementXpath throws Exception. I tried removing the throw Exception and same result.

Comment: Well if there is an exception, why not write `try..catch` inside `getElementXpath()` and see whether it catches anything.

Comment: no exception is raised....that is the weird thing. The method doesn't seem to return.

Comment: what package do you have DOMElement?

Comment: I don't see it here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swallowing an exception somewhere else seems to be the only explanations possible. Encapsulate the loop in a try-catch block, print the exception and rethrow. For testing, catch Throwable. Maybe add a finally block, too.

> My main method which executes the function getElementXpath throws Exception.

This doesn't matter, there may be a RuntimeException or even an Error. You shouldn't declare `throws Exception` without a reason, but it can't be the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

`path` is initialized with "", but never assigned again.

Comment: -1 - Answer is not relevant to the question.  (I'm sure that the OP is fully aware that his method is not complete.  It's just a demo of the problem he's trying to solve!)

Comment: You're right. After reading the faulty code, I was too much focussed on the obvious error to see, that 'NEXT ONE doesn't even print' meant doesn't even print `NEXT ONE`, not the `path` behind `NEXT ONE`. I wondered why an answer about exceptions was upvoted, but not enough. :)